Is there a way to diagnose the this PSU fault with a multimeter only (schematic provided)?
Long story short, my subwoofer has stopped working and I've narrowed the problem down to a fault in the low-power standby circuitry - it should be giving me +7V and -7V, but currently the +7V is just not there. Instead the output seems to give me unstable, fluctuating voltage between 3.5-5.5V. Even weirder still, when I remove mains power (and yes, I am handling things safely when energised), the output stabilises at +7V for ~10s as the circuit de-energises.
Initially when attempting to fix it I found a couple failed capacitors and a diode around the standby PSU outputs, and replaced them (D1, D4, D9, and C5, C26, C31 no the schematics). This fixed the -7V output which initially also didn't work correctly. The caps/diodes I replaced also matched the ones which some other people reported fail frequently on this model in avforum. But I still have a problem with the +7V output.
Here is the schematic of the circuit closest to the failing output (pin 1 on CN2) (source):

I've tried checking for continuity at various points on the output side of the PSU, as well as checking several diodes and not found any glaringly failed components (though there is a chance I missed a bunch). At this point I'm afraid I've exhausted what I can triage with the quite rusty and limited electronics knowledge of the software dev I am.
Unfortunately, at the moment I've only got a multimeter at my disposal in terms of diagnostic equipment cause I'm in between moving house (and would be keen to figure out if I can repair the sub and take it with me!)

pdf document download link

@Burglups but they seem fine when tested - i.e. the caps are not shorted and the resistor is not open

@Burglups because C26 was failed/shorted before I replaced it. C6 is not shorted.

Since then I've tried another thing - I re-checked the components I have originally replaced and it turned out that the new D4 was also blown. Replacing it again had the thing work for several seconds and then fail again. I wonder if something is wrong with the transformer or the power management IC U1.

Actually, never mind. Only just now found out that the unit is still under warranty after chatting to the manufacturer and a new board is already on its way here.
